# Is there a way to monitor a SQL Server service with ZABBIX?

Tags: sql-server-2014, zabbix

I'm reading all of that zabbix doc [That you cand find HERE](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/config/items/perfcounters) But I still can't monitor a single service.

I want to know if a service is not on "running". Any other status will send us emails.

Is there a way to achieve this?

[On this website](https://www.null-byte.org/microsoft/zabbix-monitoring-windows-services/) There's a step by step but I'm new to zabbix so it's pretty complicated to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Zabbix 3.0 manual, there is a section on [monitoring Windows services](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent/win_keys#monitoring_windows_services), which works together with [Windows service discovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery#discovery_of_windows_services). If you are using Zabbix 3.0 or later, you may find these pages useful.

In short, you should probably use a `service.info[<service>,state]` item, where `<service>` is the service you wish to monitor. If that item returns anything other than 0 (which means "running"), you may wish to alert.

The only difficulty is finding the right name of the service to use. You can either look it up in MMC Services snap-in or use LLD, as documented on the pages above.

Comment: Please refrain from answering with links only. Expand on those links, as they might be moved/removed in the future.

Comment: Thank you! Expanded the answer a bit.

Comment: Wow thank you very much. So , should I use this:
`service.info[MSSQL$DBA_SQL,0]` , ?